# What is the seaborn equivalent for matplotlilb histrogram of a column values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have code snippet in matplotlilb like below:

```
df['coln1'].plot(kind='hist') # This works!
```

I tried to use the seaborn API to plot the same and my Jupyter Notebook hangs inefinitely. I tried the code below that fails:

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df['coln1']) # What is the right way in seaborn?
```

**UPDATE**: My objective is to see visually the distribution of values for a given column, using seaborn API.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent solution to *matplotlilb* borrowed from the [seaborn official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is shown below:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

tips.head(5)
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

You can simply do this:

```
ax = sns.distplot(tips["total_bill"])
```

Which gives you the distribution of values in the "total_bill" column.

Comment: If I remove the `x=df.index`, I end up not plotting the bars for each row and end up only with one bar in the plot. I started with your solution and it didn't work breaking my assumption. I wanted to plot `col1` data for every row in the index.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking to achieve here, but that what you are saying it not common esp. with barplots, unless your data is very different that I do not understand it. And "df['coln1'].plot()" doesn't give barplot as well. This gives just line plot connecting each point in each row of that column together.  "df['coln1'].plot(kind='bar')" give barplot. What what is the point of having a barplot for each single point??

Comment: What what is the point of having a barplot for each single point?? Isn't that a very common thing. You do this to visualize the distribution of values of a particular column. And I wanted to do this using seaborn library and hence this question.

Comment: Ahun, that is not barplot, you need histogram, which is available in seaborn by seaborn.displot, see here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html!

Comment: Ignorant me! Thank you for both asking and answering right :) 

Do you mind updating  your answer with this, so I can upvote and mark it correct?

Comment: No problem. I can update my answer quickly, it is super easy. But you have to update your question as well. At the moment it is not clear what you are asking. It is only after few comments I figured what you mean. It is a good practice to have an example (few data points) to clearly ask what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(df[column], bins=bins)
```